# Parse data from string variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, variables

I want to parse data from a string variable, the example I have a data:

```
resData = [
            {
             id: 1,
             name: 'Jack',
             full_name: 'Jack Sparrow',
             avatar_url: 'http://example/img.jpg',
             ....
            },
            {
             id: 2,
             name: 'Elly',
             full_name: 'Elly Tran',
             avatar_url: 'http://example/elly.jpg',
             ....
            }
          ]

let dataStr = {
             id: 'data.id',
             html: '<strong>{{data.name}}</strong>',
             title: '<h3>{{data.full_name}}</h3>',
             icon: '{{data.avatar_url}}'
           }
```

Now how can I convert resData with a format like dataStr to:

```
dataFormated = [
            {
             id: 1,
             name: '<strong>Jack</strong>',
             full_name: '<h3>Jack Sparrow</h3>',
             avatar_url: 'http://example/img.jpg'
            },
            {
             id: 2,
             name: '<strong>Elly</strong>',
             full_name: '<h3>Elly Tran</h3>',
             avatar_url: 'http://example/elly.jpg'
            }
          ]
```

I used eval(), but not parse with string containt HTML like "name", "full_name",...

Edited!

Comment: Hope, you could write a code to do it. Do you expect the answer with code!!!

Comment: Use a templating system that supports that, like [handlebars](https://handlebarsjs.com/) or [mustache](https://mustache.github.io/).

Answer (score 0):

I updated my answer already. Please check again

```
var dataFormated = [];
var index = 0;
for (var i in resData) {
    dataFormated[index] = {
        id: resData[i].id,
        html: '<strong>' + resData[i].name + '</strong>',
        title: '<h3>' + resData[i].full_name + '</h3>',
        icon: resData[i].avatar_url
    };
    index += 1;
}
```

Comment: No, I mean is: I have an object string dataStr = {
             id: 'data.id',
             html: '<strong>{{data.name}}</strong>',
             title: '<h3>{{data.full_name}}</h3>',
             icon: '{{data.avatar_url}}'
           }

now I want to convert dataStr to dataFormated = {
            id: data.id,
            html: '<strong>' + data .name+'</strong>',
            title: '<h3>' + data.full_name + '</h3>',
            icon: data.avatar_url
        }

How can i do?

Answer (score 0):

You can use either of the following:

```
let dataFormated = resData.map(obj => (
    {
        id: obj.id,
        html: `<strong>${obj.name}</strong>`,
        title: `<h3>${obj.full_name}</h3>`,
        icon: obj.avatar_url
    }
))
```

or

```
let dataFormated = resData.map(obj => (
    {
        id: obj.id,
        html: '<strong>' + obj.name + '</strong>',
        title: '<h3>' + obj.full_name + '</h3>',
        icon: obj.avatar_url
    }
))
```

or
Using normal function as follows:

```
let dataFormated = resData.map(function(obj){
    return {
            id: obj.id,
            html: '<strong>' + obj.name + '</strong>',
            title: '<h3>' + obj.full_name + '</h3>',
            icon: obj.avatar_url
        };
})
```